# Accessing routing path string within request in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Does the Ktor framework provide a way of accessing a route's path string within a request?

For example, if I set up a route such as:

```
routing {
    get("/user/{user_id}") {
        // possible to get the string "/user/{user_id}" here?
        val path = someFunction()
        assert(path == "/user/{user_id}")
    } 
}
```

To clarify, I'm looking for a way to access the unprocessed path string, i.e. `"/user/{user_id}"` in this case (accessing the path via `call.request.path()` gives me the path after the `{user_id}` has been filled in, e.g. `"/user/123"`).

I can of course assign the path to a variable and pass it to both `get` and use it within the function body, but wondering if there's a way of getting at the route's path without doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. What you could do instead is write such a class/object

```
object UserRoutes {

    const val userDetails = "/users/{user_id}"
    ...

}
```

And reference that field from your routing module:

```
import package.UserRoutes

get(UserRoutes.userDetails) {...}
```

By doing so you would need to just reference that string from the given singleton. Also no need for the `object` wrapper but I think it looks neat that you can group the paths by *somewhat* their module name

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you are unable to statically determine your routes as explained by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62350155/430128), it is possible to determine the route at runtime via a plugin.

The plugin captures the route information and makees it available to the application as an attribute of the call context. Here is the plugin code:

```kotlin
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.application.hooks.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.util.*

val routeKey = AttributeKey<Route>("RequestRoute")

val RequestRoutePlugin = createApplicationPlugin("RequestRoutePlugin") {
  on(MonitoringEvent(Routing.RoutingCallStarted)) { call ->
    call.attributes.put(routeKey, call.route)
  }
}

fun ApplicationCall.requestRoute() = attributes[routeKey]
```

Once that plugin is installed via `install(RequestRoutePlugin)`, simply use `call.requestRoute().parent` to access the route you want. For example:

```kotlin
get("/foo/{bar}") {
  call.respondText(
    "bar=${call.parameters["bar"]} route=${call.requestRoute().parent.toString()}",
    status = HttpStatusCode.OK
  )
}
```

will respond to a request for `/foo/abc` as:

```
bar=abc route=/foo/{bar}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this

```
// Application.kt

private object Paths {
    const val LOGIN = "/login"
    ...
}

fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    ...
    routing {
       loginGet(Paths.LOGIN)
    }
}
```

And to structure my extension functions, I put them in other files like this

```
// Auth.kt

fun Route.loginGet(path: String) = get(path) {
    println("The path is: $path")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Route.fullPath(): String {
    val parentPath = parent?.fullPath() ?: "/"

    return when (selector) {
        is TrailingSlashRouteSelector,
        is AuthenticationRouteSelector,
        is HttpMethodRouteSelector,
        is HttpHeaderRouteSelector,
        is HttpAcceptRouteSelector -> parentPath
        else -> parentPath.let { if (it.endsWith("/")) it else "$it/" } + selector.toString()
    }
}

route("/user/{id}", HttpMethod.Get) {
    handle {
        val path = this@route.fullPath()
        println(path)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this problem

```
val uri = "foos/foo"

get("$uri/{foo_id}") {
    val path = call.request.path()
    val firstPart = path.length
    val secondPart = path.slice((firstPart+1) until path.length)
  
    call.respondText("$secondPart")
}
```

try this code it's simple and robust

Answer (score -2):

So all solutions so far miss the most obvious (and in my humble opinion - correct) way to extract the path variables:

```
routing {
   get("/user/{user_id}") {
       val userId = call.parameters["user_id"]
   } 
}
```

**call.parameters["user_id"]** will return a value of type **String?**

You can have multiple path variables and pull them out by this method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem I'm after - it's the exact string "/user/{user_id}" I'm looking, not the value of `user_id`.